# Build errors when building ROS 2 Humble from source on armhf architecture (BeagleBone Black, Ubuntu 22.04.3)

Tags: ros2, compilation

I have been trying to install ROS 2 Humble on a BeagleBone Black. Because of the armhf CPU architecture, I need to compile ROS from source.I followed the process described on the official ROS website.

When I do this, I got an error with the rviz package as seen below. I used other gcc versions as well as clang (by changing the environment variable for the C++ compiler) along the colcon build --ignore-errors command, the build process fails after about 6 errors(Perhaps due to a core package failing).

Thank you

Is there a specific compiler required to compile ROS2 Humble from source? Has anyone experienced issues building ROS 2 Humble from source on the armhf architecture?
Please let me know if more information is required, I am new to Linux and ROS.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Robotics StackExchange. Please keep in mind that copying and pasting your error log within a code block is preferable to sharing a screenshot, since images are not text-searchable. Also, the error that you have is related to the ogre wrapper for rviz, so maybe as a first try you can choose to ignore that particular package using `--packages-ignore` while building.